# postgresql function query execute using parameter for ANY clause - get error - query string argument of EXECUTE is null

Tags: postgresql, function, parameter-passing

PostgreSQL 11.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit

Reviewed dozens of articles in Stackoverflow, no real match. The need: pass a comma separated string (id values), and use that list with the "ANY" postgresql clause.

**Code**

```
return query execute 
  'select aa.id, aa.course_id, aa.comments, aa.curr_cont_t_id, aa.date_done, ' || 
    'aa.unit_id, aa.time_seq, aa.week_num, bb.module_id, bb.expected_hrs, ' || 
    'bb.title unit_title, cc.module_name, cc.tally_hours, cc.time_of_day, ' || 
    'bb.file_upload_expected, aa.app_files_id, xx.facility_id ' ||
  'from course_content aa ' || 
    'left outer join units bb on aa.unit_id = bb.id ' || 
    'left outer join module_categories cc on bb.module_id = cc.id ' || 
    'left outer join courses xx on aa.course_id = xx.id ' || 
  'where xx.facility_id = any(''{' || $1 || '}'') '
using p_facilities;
```

I have checked p_facilities to ensure it is not empty or null. I have even specifically set p_facilities to a value inside the function like this:

```
p_facilities text = '3';
```

The returned error is consistently: 'query string argument of EXECUTE is null (SQL State 22004)'

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL at all? Just `return (select … where xx.facility_id = any(string_to_array(p_facilities, ',')));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not referring to the `using` parameter anywhere in your query. Instead, you are concatenating `$1` directly into your query, and this `$1` refers to the first argument of the pl/pgsql function you are in (and apparently is `NULL`).

To use parameters in [dynamically executed sql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) and pass them through `using`, you need to hardcode the text `$1` into the query string:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT … WHERE xx.facility_id = any($1)' USING some_array;
```

To interpolate a string into the query, you don't need any `using` clause, just refer to the string directly:

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT … WHERE xx.facility_id = any(''{' || p_facilities || '}'')';
```

However, notice that you don't need (and shouldn't use) dynamic sql here at all. You're constructing a value, not sql structure. You can just refer to that directly in a normal query:

```
SELECT … WHERE xx.facility_id = any( ('{' || p_facilities || '}')::int[] );
-- or better
SELECT … WHERE xx.facility_id = any( string_to_array(p_facilities, ',')::int[] );
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm always a little concerned with SQL injection when using strings so I went the wrong way with this. I see the string_to_array() should protect against any SQL injection. There are other queries where I have several parameters that I use in the query (e.g. this = $1 and that = $2...). But I think you showed me how I can combine all these together.